# AngularJS generator: 'jquery.js' in top of generated scripts list in index.html

Tags: jquery, angularjs, gruntjs, bower, yeoman-generator-angular

I'm using AngularJS generator and 'm very happy about it, but I'm having a problem about the automatic generation of scripts: when I added Bootstrap, the 'grunt serve' task is generating the scripts in index.html with the jquery.js on top of it:

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-simple-logger/dist/angular-simple-logger.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/lodash/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/isteven-angular-multiselect/isteven-multi-select.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-wizard/dist/angular-wizard.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

That is indeed a problem, because some angular components enter in conflict with it.

```
{
  "name": "sms-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-google-maps": "~2.2.1",
    "angular-resource": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-touch": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.15",
    "bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
    "angular-ui-grid": "~3.0.6",
    "isteven-angular-multiselect": "angular-multi-select#~4.0.0",
    "angular-wizard": "~0.5.5",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "moduleName": "smsApp",
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "less/bootstrap.less",
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, my bootsrap.js is the last on call.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the specific problem? jQuery.js should be before angular and bootstrap.js.

Comment: Hi, when I use, for example, angular maps, I get some errors like 'Uncaught TypeError: window.initMap is not a function', etc. Or: 'You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors'

Comment: Where are you adding the google maps api? None of this is mentioned in question and has nothing to do with bootstrap or jquery

Comment: @charlietfl I read about conflicts between angular and jquery, but I'll edit the question, thx. The map is handled by angular-google-maps. But just inserting the jquery.js in second place everything works perferctly.

Comment: if you want to use jQuery in angular it needs to load before angular. Have never heard of conflicts. `angular.element` will use jQuery if it loads first. Using `bootstrap.js` however isn't worth it in angular and there are better alternatives and if you don't use bootstrap.js chances are you can remove the jQuery dependency

Comment: @charlietfl I think your answer is the key, the conflict comes when I show a map in a modal served by bootstrap.js (now we do it with ui-bootstrap). I'll do as you suggest and load only the bootstrap css. Thanks!

Comment: you can exclude jquery in wiredep session of Gruntfile and put jQuery whereever you want.

Comment: Thanks @YOU, that's a good response for somebody with a similar problem!